# Difficulty in eliminating the "\ n" as a string delimiter. (Golang)

Tags: go

I'm struglling to remove the "\ n" as a string delimiter when teh string is read from the keyboard. The objective is to identify the last letter of the string received by the keyboard input.

But it turns out that he does not identify "n" as the last letter. I think that he is save the "\n" as the last input.

Test: Try to write "ian" and it will result in "not found".

Note: I already tried use the "TrimSuffix" function, but don't solved the issue.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    str := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    fmt.Println("Please enter a string:")

    strReciv, _ := str.ReadString('\n')

    //---------------------------------------------

    s1 := strings.HasPrefix(strReciv, "i")
    s2 := strings.Contains(strReciv, "a")
    s3 := strings.HasSuffix(strReciv, "n")

    if s1 && s2 && s3 {

        fmt.Println("Found!")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Not Found")
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, the docs for `ReadString` say: _"returning a string containing the data up to and including the delimiter"_. Why didn't `TrimSuffix` work? Did you try `TrimSpace`?

Comment: The TrimSpace remove the white spaces, I don't want that, I just want the remove the "\n" at the final. I made one test to swap the delimiter to " " (space) and worked, he identified the "n" as the last letter. I don't know why when the delimiter is "\n", he keeps don't see the "n".

Comment: `ReadString` returns the delimiter at the end of the string. If I enter "ian" and click "Enter", on my Linux machine the bytes representation of `strReciv` is `[105 97 110 10]`, where the 10 is the final LF (line feed). This is why your test `s3` fails - the suffix is not 'n', it's the linefeed '\n'.

Comment: @EliBendersky, yes, this is the conclusion that I found to not work. Now I need to find a way to remove this "enter" in the final of the `s3`.

Answer (score 1):

strings.Trim works for me, as this shows

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    str := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    fmt.Println("Please enter a string:")

    sin, _ := str.ReadString('\n')
    strReciv := strings.Trim(sin, "\n")

    //---------------------------------------------

    s1 := strings.HasPrefix(strReciv, "i")
    s2 := strings.Contains(strReciv, "a")
    s3 := strings.HasSuffix(strReciv, "n")

    if s1 && s2 && s3 {

        fmt.Println("Found!")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Not Found")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of investigation, finally worked :)

I need to remove the `\r` too.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    str := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    fmt.Println("Please enter a string:")

    strIn, _ := str.ReadString('\n')
    strReciv := strings.Replace(strIn, "\r\n", "", -1)

    //---------------------------------------------

    s1 := strings.HasPrefix(strReciv, "i")
    s2 := strings.Contains(strReciv, "a")
    s3 := strings.HasSuffix(strReciv, "n")

    if s1 && s2 && s3 {

        fmt.Println("Found!")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Not Found")
    }

}
```

Carriage Return
The term CRLF refers to Carriage Return (ASCII 13, \r ) Line Feed (ASCII 10, \n ). They're used to note the termination of a line, however, dealt with differently in today's popular Operating Systems.

Comment: to make this a little more platform agnostic - look at how bufio.Scanner does it [here](https://golang.org/src/bufio/scan.go?s=11967:12045#L340). It's basically a find and replace for `\r` if it exists. `\n` is the delimiter

Comment: ah right makes sense.  @filpe, when doing questions *always* mention it's microsoft windows lots of quirks there